# Caret package not possible to install

Tags: r, caret, install.packages

I get this error on my Mac when I try to install caret with its dependencies:

```
ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/00LOCK-clock’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘clock’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘recipes’ ...
** 
Paket ‘recipes’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** 
using staged installation
** 
R
** 
inst
** 
byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading

Fehler in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘lava’
Ruft auf: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Ausführung angehalten
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘recipes’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/recipes’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘recipes’ is not available for package ‘caret’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/caret’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

I already tried to update all R packages but it did not work

Comment: Please install `recipes` package first then try to install `caret` package.

Comment: The recipes package cannot be installed either: Fehler in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘lava’
Ruft auf: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Ausführung angehalten
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘recipes’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/recipes’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Install `lava` package. Try to use `install.packages("recipes", dependencies = T)`